# magento 2 argument code enable or disable from store config

Tags: magento2

I want to enable or disable from store config with the help of 
**ifconfig** condition. How can I use this to execute my code depending on the **ifconfig** condition?

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.indexer.grid.grid.massaction">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="unsubscribeSendy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">reindex</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">reindex/index/index</item>
                    </item>                   
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

Please help if any one have idea

Comment: add `ifconfig="section/group/field"` in your **<referenceBlock>** tag

Comment: hi @DineshYadav i got Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed errot